# Using smaryt to set a last class for every 4 results not working as expected

Tags: php, smarty

I have been reading up on best method in smarty to set every 4th item in the loop a class, and came across the use of "interation" however the example code below is kind of working but it is apply the class to everything after the 4th one and im wanting to apply a last class on every 4th one. Is this possible using this method?

```
{foreach from=$product.image_pairs item="image_pair" name="additional_images"}
    {if $image_pair}
        {if $image_pair.image_id == 0}
            {assign var="img_id" value=$image_pair.detailed_id}
        {else}
        {assign var="img_id" value=$image_pair.image_id}
        {/if}
        {if $smarty.foreach.additional_images.iteration is div by 4}
            {assign var="last_image" value="last"}
        {/if}
        {include file="common_templates/image.tpl" images=$image_pair object_type="detailed_product" link_class="cm-thumbnails-mini $last_image" image_width=$th_size image_height=$th_size show_thumbnail="Y" show_detailed_link=false obj_id="`$preview_id`_`$img_id`_mini" make_box=true wrap_image=true}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Result:

```
<a class="">content</a>
<a class="">content</a>
<a class="">content</a>
<a class="">content</a>
<a class="last">content</a>
<a class="last">content</a>
<a class="last">content</a>
```

Comment: Seriously, I do not find smarty any useful. Such a drop in performance and overall overhead.

Comment: Is it possible to use CSS `nth-child` selector here?

Comment: Im happy to use CSS but need a wider range of legacy browser support on this project im afraid hence why im resulting to smarty :) and i dont have a choice at the software uses smarty templating engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{assign var="last_image" value="last"}
```

Will assign this variable on 4th iteration, and this will prevail for next iterations. You should add `else` and assign empty string to this variable.

Comment: was as simple as adding {else} and empty string as you said, thanks for your help.